# How to get number of clicks clicked on an list item in a list in Sharepoint 2013 using REST API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, rest

I am new to Sharepoint and using 2013 classic version. I have created a website and in it, it has list with items. So, I need to trace the number of clicks of each item individually. My code is not working for tracing the number of clicks as the count gets stopped with 1 and doesn't increment then for individual item. But it counts overall clicks of all items in that list. I'm stuck with this for two weeks. Please help me and Many many thanks in advance.

```
function Getprevcount(linkname) {

    var resturl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?$top=1000";

    $.ajax({

        url: resturl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },

        success: function (data) {
           var lnt = data.d.results.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < lnt; i++) {
                if (data.d.results[i].Title == linkname) {
                    prevcount = data.d.results[i].Count;
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}

   function Updatecount(updatlink) {

    var resturl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('abc')/items?$select=Title&$filter=Name";
    //alert(resturl);
    prevcount = prevcount + 1;
    //alert(prevcount);

    $.ajax({

        url: resturl,
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
            "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "IF-MATCH": "*",
            "X-HTTPS-Method": "MERGE"
        },
        data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.TestcounterListItem'},Count:'1'}",

        async: false, success: function (data) {
            alert("I'm in Update Count Section");
            console.log(prevcount);
        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON.error);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look in the update function the line below it always update with the number you can use prevcount there to update the number.

```
 data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.TestcounterListItem'},Count:'1'}",
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sir. May I have a clear information about what is data.d.results and why are we using it in REST API code?

Comment: that is the response you get from your REST call which means the result set you get from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Need to modify the line below with prevcount variable:

```
 data: "{__metadata:{'type':'SP.Data.TestcounterListItem'},Count: prevcount}",
```

Make sure the there is a field named "Count" in the Testcounter List.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, mam. May I have a clear information about what is data.d.results and why are we using it in REST API code?

Comment: @VenkatSai, data.d.results is the Rest API response data, it's json object data and in this case it's returning the previous click count for the link, you can learn about Rest API endpoint here for details:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/crud-operation-on-list-items-using-rest-api-services-in-shar/

And if the answer is helpful, you could accept as answer so that it could also be helpful to others in the forum.

Comment: Hello mam! After modifying the line with prevcount variable, I get an error as Invalid JSON. A token was not recognized in the JSON Content.